# Forcing SWF to free allocated memory from codes on FLA timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, memory-leaks

I have a Flash project and I have written some codes in timeline.  When I load SWF file and unload it the allocated memory is still there and memory leak happening every time I load and unload it.

Is there a solution for it?

I have tried this but the memory is not free.

```
addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removed);

public function removed(evt:Event) {
    removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removed);
    csc = null;
    if (currentFrame == 2) {
        content.removelisteners3()
        try {
            content.removeChildren();
        } catch (e:Error) {
        }
        menu.removeListeners1();

        try {
            mc1.mc.removeChildren();
        } catch (e:Error) {
        }
        try {
            mc1.removeChildren();
        } catch (e:Error) {
        }
    }

    if (currentFrame == 3) {
        menu.removeListeners2()
        try {
            search_ctn.removeChildren()
        } catch (e:Error) {
        }
        try {
            min_search.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, f_min_search);
        } catch (e:Error) {
        }
        try {
            clos_search.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, f_clos_search);
        } catch (e:Error) {
        }
        try {
            btnUpSearch.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, f_btnUpSearch);
        } catch (e:Error) {
        }

    }
    try {
        this.removeChildren();
    } catch (e:Error) {
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach appears rather brute force - perhaps isolating dispose functionality might help, such as within menu and in search.  Use profilers like [Adobe Scout](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scout/articles/adobe-scout-getting-started.html) to help.

Comment: You likely don't have all the listeners removed from `stage`. Also, check if `System.gc()` releases memory, but first let it run, as the `gc()` call does not force the GC to run, but rather tells Flash player to "hey, why don't you run GC now?", which FP can just ignore.

Comment: @jason: first thanks for arranging my code. It is an old file from previous programmer and I know the structure is not properly designed but I need to modify it asap without changing the structure. I dont know whats adobe scout and how it can help me :(

Comment: @Vesper I have tried to remove all listeners but it has still problem and memory leak is still happening

Comment: You (or whoever) shouldn't use frames.  Don't put code on frames, use frames to run code, etc. Use frames for animations only.  Save references to everything.  You're using removeChildren() when you should be using removeChild(arrayOfReferences[i]).

Comment: @MGol Adobe Scout is a profiler, like in other IDEs, shows things like memory allocations to help identify root cause of runtime issues.

Comment: @moot as I said this file has been written long time ago and I have to modify it. my new structure is like what you said but I need to use this old file in my project

Comment: @JasonSturges: tnx for help man :)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting stuff is no guaranty that the memory is actually freed by the garbage collector. As long as a memory location has references to it it will live on and on and....